# error when combining pageable and 'findBy' on PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a repository like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>{

    List<User> findByNameLikeIgnoreCase(String filterString, Sort sort);

    List<User> findByNameLikeIgnoreCase(String filterString, PageRequest pageRequest);

}
```

And I have a controller like this:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userDao;

    private Iterable<User> retrieveUsers(String nameToFilterBy, String orderProperty, Integer page, Integer pageSize) {
        Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, orderProperty);
        PageRequest pageRequest = page == null || pageSize == null ? null :
                                new PageRequest(page - 1, pageSize, sort); 
        String filterString = "%" + nameToFilterBy + "%";
        return pageRequest != null ? userDao.findByNameLikeIgnoreCase(filterString, pageRequest) : 
                                     userDao.findByNameLikeIgnoreCase(filterString, sort);

}
```

When `pageRequest` is set to `null`, `findByNameLikeIgnoreCase` works as expected with the `sort` parameter.

However, when `pageRequest` is not `null`, `findByNameLikeIgnoreCase` is given the pageRequest parameter and gives an error caused by `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Any tips to combine the 'findBy' functionality with pagination that doesn't give an error?

Comment: I found the fix. I changed the parameter in the method signature in the repository from `PageRequest` to `Pageable`:


`List<User> findByNameLikeIgnoreCase(String filterString, Pageable pageable)`;